# Ruby: extract text between tags and attribute of tag?

Tags: ruby

What's the easiest way to extract text between two tags as well as the attributes specified in the tag, for example:

```
some random text here
<tag id="12345">tag content A</tag>
some other random text
<tag type="mytype">
tag content B
</tag>
some more random text
```

So that I can get a list like

```rb
[{"id": "12345", "tag": "tag content A"},
 {"type": "mytype", "tag": "tag content B"}]
```

Each tag is a single line but the content between open and close tags can have multiline.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Easiest" is a matter of opinion, but what I would do is wrap the whole thing up as XML and use Nokogiri to do the work.

Let's use your sample:

```
s = <<-HERE
some random text here
<tag id="12345">tag content A</tag>
some other random text
<tag type="mytype">
tag content B
</tag>
some more random text
HERE
```

Then:

```
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri.parse("<root>#{s}</root>")
arr = []
doc.xpath('/root/*').each do |tag|
  att = tag.attributes.keys[0]
  arr << {att => tag[att], tag.name => tag.content.strip}
end
```

Now `arr` is:

```
[{"id"=>"12345", "tag"=>"tag content A"}, 
 {"type"=>"mytype", "tag"=>"tag content B"}]
```